# Complexity for a nested loop with if statement

Tags: time-complexity

what would be the complexity of the code below.  Is it still n^3?

```
for (i=1,i<n+1,i++) 
    for (j=1,j<n+1,j++)
       if (i==j)
          for (k=1,k<n+1,k++)
             print(i,j,k);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `Big-O` notation measures the upper bound, so the worst case complexity. And also it depends what you do in the `print` function, if it is constant than `O(n^3)` is the complexity.